# Get text value using name attirbute one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 elements of html

```
<h3 contenteditable class="education" name="education[index][University]>1</h3>
<span contenteditable class="education" name="education[index][time]>2</span>
<p contenteditable class="education" name="education[index][description]>3</p>
```

So i want to get text value by the order h3-span-p one by one using their name attribute by javascript.After every value i get how can i have a new line follow after like this

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: Wrap the elements in a container an iterate over the children of those elements. Otherwise you'll have to write 3 ugly (in this case given the amount of character escaping required) and brittle selectors. You could even use `map()` if you'd prefer. The output would then just be a case of generating the required HTML.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if i use this var education=$(".education").text(); i will get all the text value.Ok.But i need to have a new line after each text value i get how can i achive that.Because i want to save in db with json type

Comment: Is `.education` the element that contains these? How are you outputting the value now?

Comment: i just update html class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var output = $('[name^="education[index]"]').map(function() {
    return $(this).html();
  }).get().join('\n');
  alert(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 contenteditable name="education[index][University]">1</h3>
<span contenteditable name="education[index][time]">2</span>
<p contenteditable name="education[index][description]">3</p>
```

**UPDATE**:

if you have education class then you can just call `$('.education').map...`